# Assembling query for advanced search in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Curious if there's any way to get around the problem of building separate queries for each combination of inputs with an advanced search type functionality like so:

```
if($market_sort && $company_sort && $search){
  $text_ads = Text_ad::where('company_id','=',$company_sort)->where('market_id','=',$market_sort)->where('text','like','%'.$search.'%')->paginate(15);
  }elseif($market_sort && $company_sort && !$search){
  $text_ads = Text_ad::where('company_id','=',$company_sort)->where('market_id','=',$market_sort)->paginate(15);
  } etc etc etc
```

I tried this technique but the where clause executes the query and returns a collection object so the paginate method can no longer be called on it...

```
  $text_ads = new Text_ad;
  if($market_sort){
    $text_ads = $text_ads->where('market_id','=',$market_sort);
  }
  if($company_sort){
    $text_ads = $text_ads->where('company_id','=',$company_sort) 
  }
  $text_ads->paginate(15);
```

Comment: [You want Query Scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy is quite correct that query scope will help hide the complex query code for a sensibly-named method, but query scopes will not address the actual situation that is apparently happening, which is that for some reason `$text_ads` becomes a collection without `->get()` being called. Unfortunately I can't work out why that's happening with the code pasted, but just wanted to point out that query scopes *should* be used, but don't solve this issue.

Comment: That said, when you're calling `new Text_ad` you should really be calling `Text_ad::newQuery()`. Again it shouldn't make a difference to the issue here, but it is more correct and incurs slightly less overhead.

Comment: I just tested this on Laravel 4.1 and it's working fine, the second method that is.  Are you sure you don't have some code anywhere that could possibly be messing with the results?  I see you are missing a semicolon, but I'm assuming that's a typo.

Comment: actually I just got it to work by changing the last line to $text_ads = $text_ads->paginate(15); I was wrong about the collection object returning, I assumed that because of an error paginate was creating in the view

Comment: I would still recommend using Query Scopes anyway! It will keep your code cleaner and more organized, and I feel it better implements the ORM principle